# Min Unique Characters

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm

REF: Ques 5 on this link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/directi-programming-questions

Given: two strings X and Y , with only one operation possible i.e swap the corresponding letters of X and Y ( i.e. X[i] and Y[i] ) which can be performed any number of times.

```
n(X) : number of unique characters in X
n(Y) : number of unique characters in Y
```

Problem : By Using the swap operations , Find the minimum possible values of max(n(X),n(Y))

```
INPUT:
ababa
babab

OUTPUT:
1
--------------------
INPUT:
abaaa
baaac

OUTPUT:
2
```

Please help me correct my solution or solve this problem with a better approach.
My Approach (Works For first and many other testcases but not the second one ) :

```
    for(int i=0; i<x;i++)
    {
        if((count1[st1[i]]!=-1)||(count2[st2[i]]!=-1))
        {
            if(st1[i]!=st2[i])
            {
            if(count1[st1[i]]!=-1)
            count1[st1[i]]++;

            if(count2[st2[i]]!=-1)
            count2[st2[i]]++;
            }
            else 
            {
            ans++;
            count1[st1[i]]=-1;
            count2[st1[i]]=-1;
            }
        }
    }


  for(int i=97;i<123;i++)
  {
    if(count1[i]>0)
    c1++;
    if(count2[i]>0)
    c2++;
    if((count1[i]>0)&&(count2[i]>0))
    com++;
  }

    un = max(c1,c2);
    ans+= un-com/2;
    printf("%lld\n",ans);
```

Comment: "with only one operation possible..." - Is not the `for`, `++` etc. other operations. Should the other operations not be possible as well.

Comment: It is not possible. Add other operations. How about comparing two characters?

Comment: I guess the question is as follows: using this swap operation, make two strings that `max(n(X),n(Y))` is as minimum as possible. So the limitation on the operation is not what you are allowed in a program.

Comment: @Petr Yes , I corrected it.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a link to the actual challenge, because your wording is rather confusing.

Comment: @n.m. Ques 5 on this link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/directi-programming-questions/

Comment: Edit your question, don't add comments here. That said, in the first example, there are no unique characters in either string, so the result should be zero, IMHO. Also, please decide for one programming language.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The Question has been edited already. By unique , they mean the number of distinct characters i.e. 'aa' and 'aaaa' , both have answer 1 as number of  distinct character.

Comment: Firstly, if you mean distinct, then don't write unique! Further, "ababa", "babab" and "abaaa" are made of two distinct characters, while "baaac" is made of three. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood your algorithm, but here is brute-force version, which works for strings up-to 64 symbols length:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define max(a,b) (a >= b ? a : b)
#define min(a, b) (a <= b ? a : b)
#define swap(a, b, idx) (a[idx] = a[idx] ^ b[idx] ^ (b[idx] = a[idx]))

int unique(char*a) {
    char c[256] = { 0 };
    int u = 0;
    while (*a) {
        u += (c[*a] == 0);
        c[*a++] = 1;
    }
    return u;
}

void swapWithMask(char* a, char* b, unsigned long int mask, int l) {
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
        if ((mask & (1 << j)) != 0)
            swap(a, b, j);
}

int minUnique(char*oa, char*ob) {
    int l = strlen(oa);
    int minu = l;

    char *a = malloc(l + 1);
    strcpy(a, oa);
    char *b = malloc(l + 1);
    strcpy(b, ob);

    unsigned long int m = (1 << l);
    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        swapWithMask(a, b, i, l);
        minu = min(max(unique(a), unique(b)), minu);
        swapWithMask(a, b, i, l);
    }

    free(b);
    free(a);
    return minu;
}

int main(void) {
    puts((minUnique("directi", "itcerid") == 4) ? "ok" : "fail");
    puts((minUnique("ababa", "babab") == 1) ? "ok" : "fail");
    puts((minUnique("abaaa", "baabb") == 2) ? "ok" : "fail");
    return 0;
}
```